# Image Color Shows Through Linear Gradient on Corners

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, gradient

I am trying to make little cards on my website that show an image and then have a gradient that goes from transparent to black top to bottom. The gradient is so I can have a background for text I want to show over the image. I have the image on the card and the gradient however there is weird artifacting where about a 1 px line on both bottom corners shows the color of the background image. I can't seem to figure out how to fix it but it seems to be due to the overflow: hidden CSS property.

I was able to re-create this in a codepen instead so here is the basic HTML and CSS

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="project-card-details">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #060b10;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: steelblue;
}

.project-card-details {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, black 80%);
}
```

Here is an image of what is happening

[Corner Artifacting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1kJY.png)

I tried moving where the gradient is applied but nothing really made a difference. I can see that the artifact appears as soon as I apply the overflow: hidden property so I believe it has something to do with that behavior.

Comment: _"This is with a React Component so I will provide the component code as well as the CSS."_ - this would probably be much easier for the majority of people here to test, if you gave us the rendered HTML instead.

Comment: Edited with HTML and CSS instead